# How to enable intellisense for tensorflow in visual studio code

Tags: tensorflow, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I wish to enable intellisense for visual studio code for faster development is there any way to do that.

Comment: All I could find for that is this: https://github.com/alexwalchli/visualstudiocode-tensorflow

There is no extension for tensorflow, are you sure intellisense for it exists?

Comment: any updates in 2020?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should enable intellisense.

github.com/alexwalchli/visualstudiocode-tensorflow